# Replace links in Mysql

Tags: mysql, regex

It is really beyond my scope the task I am looking for, I have searched and tried a dozen of things but I am not confident at all with regular expressions.

I have a blog, where I have mentioned several hundred times books from Amazon. I would like to change all this links with affiliated. I have done it in a 10% of the posts, but its so slow!

So please if someone can help, I would appreciate. I just want to replace all occurrences of:

```
http://www.amazon.com/[whatever but not |myafiliated-01]">
```

with:

```
http://www.amazon.com/[whatever&tag=myafiliated-01]">
```

I think it is impossible with a simple mysql query. Tried exporting to a text editor but it is perhaps also too much.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try this query -

```
SELECT REPLACE('http://www.amazon.com/[whatever but not |myafiliated-01]">', ' but not |', '&tag=');
```

or try to select replaced data from your table -

```
SELECT REPLACE(column_name, ' but not |', '&tag=') FROM table_name;
```

If result is OK, then try to update your table -

```
UPDATE table_name SET column_name = REPLACE(column_name, ' but not |', '&tag=');
```

You also can add a WHERE condition, e.g. WHERE column_name LIKE '% but not |%'.